# laravel 5.2 greggilbert/recaptcha : array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array

Tags: php, laravel, recaptcha

I installed greggilbert/recaptcha in my laravel 5.2 project. I followed the direction accordingly described here:https://github.com/greggilbert/recaptcha

But when I opened the form where I used recaptcha, I found the above message. 
I read the source code but understand nothing. 
Can anybody help me in this regard to find any solution?
Thanks in advance.

Here is my form HTML Code

```
@section('form')
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'contact')) }}
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment blue"></i></span>
                <textarea name="InputMessage" rows="6" class="form-control" required placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        {!! Recaptcha::render() !!}
        <div class="">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Send <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
            <button type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset" class="btn">Reset <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>

{{Form::close()}}
@endsection
```

Comment: Show us some code! :)

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is solved.

The problem was:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Greggilbert\Recaptcha\RecaptchaServiceProvider"`
```

command did nothing. 
So `recaptcha.php` file was not copied to root config folder.

I copied the `recaptcha.php` file from

```
vendor > greggilbert > recaptcha > src > config > recaptcha.php`
```

to config folder and the problem disappears.

Answer (score 0):

After vendor publishing you need to clear config cache using command

> php artisan config:cache